# How to set the menu bar direction to right to left (RTL) in ElectronJS

Tags: electron, arabic, arabic-support

I'm building an ElectronJS app in Arabic but I'm not able to set the menu bar direction to right to left (RTL).

I even tried to change the dir attribute of the body tag but it didn't work too.

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electron should automatically respect the configuration of the operating system. You can activate RTL by running the electron with the rtl parameter as follows.

--force-ui-direction=rtl

However, the RTL orientation of the menu itself cannot be configured.

Also see [this](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-10-0#breaking-changes)

Thanks and best regards!